# Identity function is a homeomorphism iff topologies are equal

Tags: functions

Let  $\tau_1$  and $\tau_2$ are two topologies on $X$
Then the function $f: (X,\tau_1) \to (X,\tau_2)$ defined by $f(x)=x$ is a homeomorphism if and only if $\tau_1=\tau_2$

I have tried many many unnecessary properties and I am in a jam now. I need exact and clear two directioned proof. Can someone illuminate me or direct me to exact proof? (Without using f is a homeomorphism iff f is open and continuous)

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is a homeomorphism iff both $f:(X,\tau_1)\to (X,\tau_2)$
and $f^{-1}:(X,\tau_2)\to (X,\tau_1)$ are both continuous.
$f:(X,\tau_1)\to (X,\tau_2)$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}(U)\in\tau_1$
for all $U\in\tau_2$. But $f^{-1}(U)=U$, so $f$ is continuous
iff $\tau_2\subseteq\tau_1$. Now what is the condition that
$f^{-1}:(X,\tau_2)\to (X,\tau_1)$ be continuous.?

Comment: $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2 $ from that. Should I use bijectivity for other direction, could you please hint?